# How does a GUI program in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp run before there is a login?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I stuck a Taskmgr.exe shortcut in, thinking it would run at *login* (like shell:startup) but for all users.  However, I noticed after rebooting, when I log in as an ordinary user, the Task Manager is already running.

How can a GUI program be running if there's no login?

Also, I don't see it start when I log in using an administrator account.

Answer (score 1):

Task Manager (at least for some time now) does not start with a regular shortcut. It is a special type of Windows app and does not start that way.

There is a setting in Settings that will restart Task Manager. I have used that. Default is to have this setting enabled. This is what is very likely happening in your system.

It is also possible that Task Manager is restarting because it was running. I have seen this behavior in Windows Insider, so this is somewhat of a work in progress.

[image]

Comment: Interesting feature.  I don't have Restart apps enabled so I wonder how taskmgr.exe is running.  There's nothing in the task scheduler that would launch this.

Comment: I have tried to start Task Manager with a Scheduled Task (set for admin, and to start at startup) but that has not worked. The setting I showed, if enabled and if TM is running will restart TM.  I have done this. I normally shut everything down and have the setting above disabled as I do not want things starting on the own except for the services I want starting.

Comment: I also tried task scheduler in the past but had no success.  The current setup seems to be working for non-admin accounts, but it's a head scratcher.

Comment: It is a bit of a strange App. It is built right in. Starting automatically depends on the system, version and settings. It uses 100% CPU immediately after starting for 5 seconds or so and goes back to normal. How it starts depends in part in the exact setup.